# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, browser, object-reference

That's my code:

```
    Dim num as integer = 0
    For Each s As String In ListBox1.Items
        num = num + 1
        Dim web(num) As WebBrowser
        RefreshIESettings(s)
        Web(num).Navigate("http://www.google.com") 'There's the error
        wait("5000")
        MsgBox(Web(num).Document.Title)
    Next
```

And I get this error only if I do this:

```
    Dim webb As WebBrowser
    RefreshIESettings(s)
    Webb.Navigate("http://www.google.com") 'Here too
    wait("5000")
    MsgBox(Webb.Document.Title)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Like @dotTutorials mentioned, I think you should have another look at the [New Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VB.NEW%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true) from MSDN and maybe you should do some basic tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you create an array of null references:

```
Dim web(num) As WebBrowser
```

You need to set the value of `web(num)` before using it, or it will just be null.

Just change your code to include

```
web(num) = New WebBrowser()
```

before you use `web(num)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "new" keyword.

Both here:

```
Dim num as integer = 0
    For Each s As String In ListBox1.Items
        num = num + 1
        Dim web(num) As WebBrowser = new WebBrowser()
        RefreshIESettings(s)
        Web(num).Navigate("http://www.google.com")
        wait("5000")
        MsgBox(Web(num).Document.Title)
    Next
```

And here:

```
    Dim webb As WebBrowser = new WebBrowser()
    RefreshIESettings(s)
    Webb.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
    wait("5000")
    MsgBox(Webb.Document.Title)
```